# Should I be considering a Accelerated Master Program?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate

I'm a 3rd year undergrad in Mathematics and Chemistry. I find most of subjects I have encountered very interesting, like computer science, physics and my two majors. I try to be involved with projects with professors from different fields. I'm having a hard time to decide what I truly want to do. That's why I want to learn more about each subjects. Should I focus on one thing at a time?

The decision I need to make right now is that, I found two Accelerated Master Program (AMP) in both Chemistry and Computer science. They are both 5 years program. The deadline is the second semester of junior year. I heard from my Chemistry adviser that I cannot use any AMP credit to fulfill part of a PhD if I changed my mind later. I think AMP is a good chance for me to have a better view of those subjects without committing 5-6 years PhD work. I'm afraid once I go in depth and I find I like it then I will have to spend more time later.

*Is it more advisable to pursue an accelerated masters program or just a bachelors degree when planning on possibly pursuing PhD program latter?*

Comment: Please specify your goals and the context you are working in (country, institution type, funding...) and try to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to change your thinking style. There are many things we are passionate about them, but the life is too short and there is always a career competition. Therefore, most of us could be successful in one branch.
I suggest specify a deadline for yourself, ask others in these fields and at some point decide when your decision deadline come. By deciding I mean throw away all the other subjects completely from your mind.

Comment: This answer would probably be more useful if you would offer some supporting logic or explanation beyond "life is too short."